# передавать CSS свойство от одного блока к другому

Tags: javascript, css, style

придумал вот такую строку:

```
prev.style.backgroundImage = divs[a].style.backgroundImage;
```

для того, чтобы передавать `background-image` свойство от одного блока к другому.

данный метод не работает, как заставить его работать? Изначально CSS свойства `prev` пусты. `div` и `prev` используются и работают.

может такая строка вообще не правильна?

Answer (score 2):

Будет работать, если у первого елемента уже есть бекграунд. Тогда каждый текучий елемент будет брать `background-image` предыдущего.
Также, нужно начинать цикл со второго елемента.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
divs[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('test.png')";
for(var i = 1; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].style.backgroundImage = divs[i-1].style.backgroundImage;
}
```